# Node.js read a file in a zip without unzipping it

Tags: javascript, node.js, zip

I have a zip file (actually it's an epub file) I need to loop through the files in it and read them without unzipping them to the disk.

I tried to use a Node.js library called `JSZip` but the content of each file is stored in memory in Buffer and whenever I try to decode the buffer content to string the content returned is unreadable

Here's the code I tried:

```
const zip = new JSZip();
  // read a zip file
    fs.readFile(epubFile, function (err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;
        zip.loadAsync(data).then(function (zip) {
            async.eachOf(zip.files, function (content, fileName, callback) {
                if (fileName.match(/json/)) {
                    var buf = content._data.compressedContent;
                    console.log(fileName);
                    console.log((new Buffer(buf)).toString('utf-8'));
                }
                callback();
            }, function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 27):

Since unzip seems to be abandoned, I used [node-stream-zip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-stream-zip) with pretty good success.

```
npm install node-stream-zip
```

Reading files be all like:

```
const StreamZip = require('node-stream-zip');
const zip = new StreamZip({
    file: 'archive.zip',
    storeEntries: true
});

zip.on('ready', () => {
    // Take a look at the files
    console.log('Entries read: ' + zip.entriesCount);
    for (const entry of Object.values(zip.entries())) {
        const desc = entry.isDirectory ? 'directory' : `${entry.size} bytes`;
        console.log(`Entry ${entry.name}: ${desc}`);
    }

    // Read a file in memory
    let zipDotTxtContents = zip.entryDataSync('path/inside/zip.txt').toString('utf8');
    console.log("The content of path/inside/zip.txt is: " + zipDotTxtContents);

    // Do not forget to close the file once you're done
    zip.close()
});
```

Answer (score 10):

```
npm install unzip
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/unzip

```
    fs.createReadStream('path/to/archive.zip')
  .pipe(unzip.Parse())
  .on('entry', function (entry) {
    var fileName = entry.path;
    var type = entry.type; // 'Directory' or 'File' 
    var size = entry.size;
    if (fileName === "this IS the file I'm looking for") {
      entry.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('output/path'));
    } else {
      entry.autodrain();
    }
  });
```

Comment: How would you use the entry as a read stream? I'm trying to pipe it to s3

Comment: unzip hasn't been updated in 4 years. The project is dead - https://github.com/EvanOxfeld/node-unzip/issues/81

Comment: I'm sure @BigMoney has figured this out by now, but to pipe the file to S3 you would append an additional pipe to a PassThrough stream, and provide the PassThrough stream as the body parameter to S3. 

Using Pipeline would be preferred over calling .pipe on each stream.