# Compare files to files inside a Zip archive

Tags: zip

I have a zip file which I extract to a folder. I then need to open the files and perform various functions but the files are not modified or saved at all.

I use Dotnetzip to extract the files from the archive before the files are opened and viewed etc.

Is there a way to compare the files, which was extracted, to the files still inside the zip file without extracting those files again? The zip files I have is quite large. Some of them several 100 Mb's so don't want to wait for another extraction process again.
Thanks!

Comment: this would help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/51910663/8087468