# List zip file entries with special characters like emojis

Tags: bash, zip, unzip

I'm writing a script that needs to list file entries from a zip file. My problem is that when there is an entry with an emoji, and the CLI doesn't output the file name correctly:

```sh
❯ zip -r foo.zip test/
  adding: test/ (stored 0%)
  adding: test/.txt (stored 0%)

src on main [!?] is  v1.0.0 via  v16.14.0 
❯ unzip -l foo.zip 
Archive:  foo.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  04-08-2022 20:54   test/
        0  04-08-2022 20:54   test/�???.txt  <---- here is my problem
---------                     -------
        0                     2 files

src on main [!?] is  v1.0.0 via  v16.14.0 
❯ unzip foo.zip test/.txt
Archive:  foo.zip
 extracting: test/�???.txt
```

Is there a way to tell `unzip` to list the file entries with consideration of special characters?

Thanks!

Comment: Works fine for me on Ubuntu 21.04.  What OS are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem possible to accurately list the files in a zip archive with `unzip` (tested with `unzip 6.00`); you'll have to select an other tool.

I chose `perl` in my answer because it has the required functionality in its core library. Here I used a `newline` as delimiter (`-l`) but you should replace it with a `NULL-BYTE` (`-l0`) if you want to be able to read and process the outputted paths 100% accurately from bash:

```sh
perl -l -e '
    use IO::Uncompress::Unzip;
    $zip = IO::Uncompress::Unzip->new($ARGV[0]);
    while($zip->nextStream()) {
        print $zip->getHeaderInfo()->{Name}
    }
' foo.zip
```

```
test/
test/.txt
```

---

**remark:** Python also have a `ZipFile` module in its core library. I didn't post any Python solution because of the encoding issues of its `stdout`. The fixes aren't compatible between Python versions...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm writing a Node.js script, so I'll try to find a package that can read the entry files there. Thanks!

Comment: @DanielRamos That would be the best solution for your use-case ;-) It seems like it can be done with https://stackoverflow.com/a/51910663/3387716

Comment: I've tried `zipinfo` linux util, but no success

Comment: `zipinfo` is an alias for `unzip -Z` so it's expected that it won't work if you had problems with `unzip -l`. But haven't you already decided to use an external NodeJS package like `node-stream-zip`?

Comment: Yes! I endend using `node-steam-zip`, which worked as a charm, thanks a lot for your help!