# Read a file buffer from .zip file buffer data in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, zip, buffer

I call an API which returns a buffer data of a .zip file. I want to read files' buffer data which resides inside the .zip file using its buffer data without saving the .zip file. Is it possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js read a file in a zip without unzipping it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39705209/node-js-read-a-file-in-a-zip-without-unzipping-it)

Comment: The two answers rely on a saved .zip files in the system but in my case its working .zip file buffer data. It means that there is no .zip file path only buffer data to work with.

Answer (score 2):

Try the `zlib` library (its a core node.js library - docs: https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html#zlib), with this example I took from the documentation

```
const {unzip } = require('node:zlib');


const buffer = Buffer.from('eJzT0yMAAGTvBe8=', 'base64');
unzip(buffer, (err, buffer) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('An error occurred:', err);
    process.exitCode = 1;
  }
  console.log(buffer.toString());
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can we get the buffers of each file included in zip file after unzipping it? If yes, how?